# PHPMAILER, how to redirect to the thank you page after submitting the form?

Tags: phpmailer

After completing the registration form, I want you to be sent a message saying "Your message is being sent" and then be directed to the thank you page.
But I couldn't because I don't have much js and php knowledge.
PHP MAILER Version: Latest Version

Resigtration.html JS Code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                function send_special_order() {
                var data1 = $('#fname').val();
                var data2 = $('#lname').val();
                var data3 = $('#dob').val();
                var data4 = $('#gender').val();
                var data5 = $('#veliad').val();
                var data6 = $('#vsoyad').val();
                var data7 = $('#phone').val();
                var data8 = $('#email').val();
                var data9 = $('#adres').val();      
                var data10 = $('#Location').val();

                  $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "registration.php",
                  dataType : "json",
                  data: ( {"fname" : data1, "lname" : data2, "dob" : data3,"gender" : data4,"veliad" : data5,"vsoyad" : data6,"phone" : data7,"email" : data8,"adres" : data9,"Location" : data10}  ) ,
                  success: function() {},
                  complete: function() {
                    $('#feedback').append('<p>Bize mesaj gönderdiğiniz için teşekkür ederiz. Uzmanlarımız en kısa sürede sizinle iletişime geçecektir.</p>');
                    $('#contact-form').slideUp();
                  }
                });
              }
              $('#contact-form').submit(function() {
                send_special_order();
                return false;
              });
            </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkForm(form) // Submit button clicked
  {
    //
    // check form input values
    //

    form.myButton.disabled = true;
    form.myButton.value = "Gönderiliyor...";
    return true;
  }

  function resetForm(form) // Reset button clicked
  {
    form.myButton.disabled = false;
    form.myButton.value = "Submit";
  }

</script>
```

Registration.php Page code

```
if(!$mail->Send()){
                echo "Mesaj hatası: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
                echo "Mesaj Gönderildi";
}

?>
```

Comment: You're using a very old version of PHPMailer that is buggy and vulnerable to several serious attacks. I recommend you [upgrade to the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I upgraded, but I couldn't solve my problem. I want the browser to redirect to the thanks page after the form is submitted. Is it possible to help?

Comment: I didn’t post that as an answer, just advice. Your question has nothing to to do with PHPMailer, it’s  “how do I issue a redirect from Javascript”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following code.

```
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "registration.php",
          dataType : "json",
          data: ( {"fname" : data1, "lname" : data2, "dob" : data3,"gender" : data4,"veliad" : data5,"vsoyad" : data6,"phone" : data7,"email" : data8,"adres" : data9,"Location" : data10}  ) ,
         success: function (form) { },
          complete: function() {
            $('#feedback').append('<p>Bize mesaj gönderdiğiniz için teşekkür ederiz. Uzmanlarımız en kısa sürede sizinle iletişime geçecektir.</p>');
            $('#contact-form').slideUp();
             window.location.replace("/tesekkurler.html");
          }
        });
      }
      $('#contact-form').submit(function() {
        send_special_order();
        return false;
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search some knowledge about it.
To explain you a bit :

in your $.ajax() you will make a POST Request [POST AND GET REQUEST](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

in this request you have a `success: function() {}`

this "success" function will be called once your request is success.

So in this function you can implement what you want to do next.

A basic way of prompting a message using [alert()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp)

and to redirect your user :

you can use [window.location](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp) to the desire url

For example i take only your Ajax sample :

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "registration.php",
          dataType : "json",
          data: ( {"fname" : data1, "lname" : data2, "dob" : data3,"gender" : data4,"veliad" : data5,"vsoyad" : data6,"phone" : data7,"email" : data8,"adres" : data9,"Location" : data10}  ) ,
          success: function() {
                  alert("This is a success");
                  window.location.replace("http://yourwebsite/thankspage");
           },
          complete: function() {
            $('#feedback').append('<p>Bize mesaj gönderdiğiniz için teşekkür ederiz. Uzmanlarımız en kısa sürede sizinle iletişime geçecektir.</p>');
            $('#contact-form').slideUp();
          }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, when I made the change you said in my ajax code, I couldn't get the redirect to the thank you page.